# How to have a composite id where fields are available in multiple embedded classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

The composite key for my table is userid, orderno, orderstatus.

Entity class is

```
@Entity
public class OrTest implements java.io.Serializable {

  private UserInfo user;   //UserInfo is embedded class having userid
  private OrderInfo order; // OrderInfo is embedded class having order
  private Status  status;  //Status is embedded class having orderstatus
  //Contains other misc info

}
```

How to use embeddedid in this scenario where my actual composite key fields are split across multiple embedded classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can have EmbeddedId class contain all the 3 keys. like below

```
public class OrTextPk implements Serializable{
     @Column(name="userId")
     public String userId;
     @Column(name="orderNo")
     public String orderNo'
     @Column(name="orderStatus")
     public String orderStatus;
}
```

Now, in the OrText class you can do the following.

```
@Entity
public class OrTest implements java.io.Serializable {

  @EmbeddedId
  private OrTextPk id;

  @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="userId")
  private UserInfo user;   //UserInfo is embedded class having userid
  .
  .
  . 
  so on...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. I was facing "Repeated column in mapping for hibernate entity userid. I tried with insertable=false , updatable = false in my UserInfo class. Now it is correctly working. But this does not help my purpose because now I need to set the data correctly in OrTextPk as you have mentioned, and anything that is mentioned in userId for UserInfo object is not reflected. But it should be viceversa where the data I set in UserInfo.userid must be reflected in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution posted by @Zeus, You only need to do minor change in following way.

Composite PK

```
public class OrTextPk implements Serializable{
 public String userId;
 @Column(name="orderNo")
 public String orderNo'
 @Column(name="orderStatus")
 public String orderStatus;
}
```

Main entity class

```
@Entity 
public class OrTest implements java.io.Serializable {
 @EmbeddedId
 private OrTextPk id;

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 // Note: it will help to map value of userId (UserInfo) to Pk object
 @MapsId("userId")  
 @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
 private UserInfo user;   //UserInfo is embedded class having userid
 .
      .
      .
 so on...
}
```

Now, on setting New/Persisted object of `UserInfo`(user), value of `userId` of `UserInfo` object will be assigned to `userId` of `OrTextPk` while persisting `OrTest` object.